# how to convert pixel into percentage measurement in html?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, pixel

I've designed one web site from asp.net & in that i designed the html pages with the help of css. In that css all the measurement that i've taken are in pixel. I want to convert all from pixel to percentage?

Is there any conversion formula for this?

how to do this?

thanks.

Comment: For font sizes or something else?

Comment: Percentages are based on *something*. `100%` is `100%` of some base value, which you have to define.

Comment: I set width,font-size,height like wise.. for all these values i want to convert them into percentage.

Answer (score 1):

To change the width of a block element to a percentage value, you'll have to know the width of its container in the same units.

```
var widthChildPercent = widthChildPixels / widthParentPixels;
```

Obviously, you'll likely want to format that to an integer value when you update the style, but that will be the general formula.

Comment: not necessary an "integer". you're allowed decimals in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use [THIS](http://www.uniteasy.com/en/unitsCon/empxpec.htm) to convert your pixel values to percentage

Answer (score 0):

I use the following formula when converting for a flexible layout from a static layout:

```
result = 100 * target / context
```

where

- `target` is what you want to change
- `context` is (usually) the page width you want to work with.

For example, if you have a block element `<section>` that currently has a width of 330px and you are working in a wrapper of 1024px, you could use `330/1024*100` which gives you a result of 32.23% for your width. However, as a rule, for fonts you want to convert to `em` rather than percentages.